# How to let user choose how many checkboxes can be selected in Element-ui?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm making a create question page, and would like to let the user creating the question to be able to select how many options need to be selected for the question, like 1 as default and they can choose to let 2 or 3 options be chosen. How can I do this for the Element-ui checkbox component?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can make a list of question and use a v-for

```
<template>

    <el-checkbox-group 
       v-model="questionCheck"
        :min="1"
        :max="3">
     <el-checkbox v-for="(question,key) in questions" :label="question" :key="key"> 
           {{question}}
     </el-checkbox>
</el-checkbox-group>   
 </template>
 <script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
      questionCheck: ['question one', 'question two'],
      questions: ['question one', 'question two','question tree']
    };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: maybe I didn't explain myself correctly, what I want is an option where the person creating the question can choose if the user is to input only one option, two options or however many options the person creating the question wants. That way when the user is answering the question it will show `you must select x amount of options`

Comment: well you can say when they are creating the question that put a field of number of options for that question,.

Comment: I mean more how to use that value later on to make sure only that many options are being selected

Comment: the <el-checkbox-group> has a prop that is min you can put the store value in there like :min="numberOptions"

Comment: or you can check before save if  numberOptions >= questionCheck.length